# generate new column using other columns

Tags: t-sql

I am stuck with generating a new column. The table has three columns(C_ID, C_rank, Date).

```
C_ID C_ Rank NewColumn(Cycle) Date
 42     A        1            October 14, 2010
 42     B        1            October 26, 2010
 42     A        2            February 16, 2011

 43     A        1            December 17, 2010

 44     A        1            July 28, 2010
 44     B        1            August 10, 2010
 44     A        2            January 11, 2011
 44     B        2            January 28, 2011

 45     A        1            July 30, 2010
 45     B        1            August 9, 2010
 45     B        1            September 24, 2010
 45     A        2            April 5, 2011
 45     B        2            April 26, 2011
```

I want to generate one more column called `Cycle` in such a way that for each `C_ID`, it should generate the number start from one and increment the number from next `C_rank = 'A'` (a shown above).

I tried using row_number, but no luck.

Maybe some loop option till next `C_Rank = 'A'` works.

How can this be done?

Comment: I follow all the way up until a few rows in the '45 group. `45 B 1 September 24, 2010`. Shouldn't that `1` be a `2`? Shouldn't `45 B 2 April 26, 2011` be `3`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this done using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY`

```
;WITH YourDataCTE AS
(
   SELECT
      C_ID, C_Rank, Date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C_ID,C_Rank ORDER BY Date DESC) AS 'Cycle'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM YourDataCTE
```

Does that do what you're looking for??

The `PARTITION BY C_ID,C_Rank` will cause the `ROW_NUMBER` to start at 1 again for each different value of `C_ID,C_Rank` - I didn't know what `ORDER BY` clause within a single partition (a single value of `C_ID,C_Rank`) you're looking for and just guessed it might be `Date DESC` (newest date first).

Comment: This assigns increasing numbers for each row in a `C_ID, Rank` group.  Not what the question was asking for

Comment: @Andomar: hmm.... yes, seems the OP's requirements is even more complicated than this.... not sure how that requirement could be easily fulfilled....

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of previous `A`'s in a subquery:

```
select  *
,       (
        select  count(*)
        from    @YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.C_ID = yt1.C_ID
                and yt2.C_Rank = 'A'
                and yt2.Date <= yt1.Date
        ) as Cycle
from    @YourTable yt1
order by
        C_ID, Date
```

[Example at ODATA.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/100790/)

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join for all records with the same C_ID, a previous date, and a C_Rank='A' and count them.

```
select t1.C_ID, t1.C_Rank, count(t2.C_Rank) Cycle, t1.Date
from MyTable t1
  left join MyTable t2 on t1.C_ID=t2.C_ID
                      and t2.Date<=t1.Date
                      and t2.C_Rank='A'
group by t1.C_ID, t1.C_Rank, t1.Date
order by t1.C_ID, t1.Date
```

Comment: Thanks Chezy, You are right, performance degrades with counters!! your code work with my requiremnt too with less execution time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code fulfill the requirement:

```
create table #Temp_Table
(
C_ID int
, C_Rank char(1)
, Date datetime
, NewColumn int
)

insert into #Temp_Table
(
C_ID
, C_Rank
, Date
)
select 42, ‘A’, ’10/14/2010′
union all
select 42, ‘B’, ’10/26/2010′
union all
select 42, ‘B’, ’10/14/2010′
union all
select 42, ‘C’, ’10/26/2010′
union all
select 42, ‘A’,’02/16/2011′
union all
select 43, ‘A’, ’12/17/2010′
union all
select 44, ‘A’, ’07/28/2010′
union all
select 44, ‘B’, ’08/10/2010′
union all
select 44, ‘A’, ’01/11/2011′
union all
select 44, ‘B’, ’01/28/2011′
union all
select 44, ‘C’, ’10/14/2010′
union all
select 44, ‘D’, ’10/26/2010′

Select ‘Original Data’ Comment
,*
from #Temp_Table

/*
This would be Actual Script to get the New ID based on information you provided
*/
Declare @Count int
,@C_ID int
,@C_Rank char(1)
,@total_Count int
,@Count_Partition int
,@Previous_ID int 

Declare @Table Table (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), C_ID int, C_Rank char(1), Date datetime, NewColumn int )

Set @Count = 1
Set @Count_Partition = 0

insert into @Table
Select *
from #Temp_Table 

Select @total_Count = ISNULL(MAX(ID),0)
from @Table

While @Count < = @total_Count
Begin
Select @C_ID = C_ID
,@C_Rank = C_Rank
From @Table
Where ID = @Count

If @Count = 1
Set @Previous_ID = @C_ID

If @Previous_ID != @C_ID
Set @Count_Partition = 1

Else If @C_Rank = 'A'
Set @Count_Partition = @Count_Partition + 1

update @Table
Set NewColumn = @Count_Partition
Where ID = @Count

Set @Previous_ID = @C_ID
Set @Count = @Count + 1
End 

Select C_ID
, C_Rank
, [Date]
, NewColumn
from @Table

–Drop table #Temp_Table
```

Comment: I use counters for getting Cycle value.

Comment: A loop like that should really be avoided in SQL.  Try running this on a few thousand records and you'll see what I mean.